# Javascript Regexp replace according to mask

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to format a string, according to a given mask built of asterisks and special characters.

The asterisks in the mask represent the characters in the given string, and the other special characters in the mask should be added to the given string in correct place - according to their location in the mask.

examples:

**1.** String: `"123456789"`, mask: `"(***)-***-***"`, output should be: "`(123)-456-789"`

**2.** String: `"123456"`, mask: `"***-** *"`, output should be: `"123-45 6"`

I also have to support partial match, suppose in example one it is as following:

String: `"12345"`, mask: `"(***)-***-***"`, output should be: `"(123)-45"`

I am searching for a solution in javascript + regex use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `replaceAll` with callback function. There is no need for a regular expression here:

```js
function applyMask(str, mask) {
    let i = 0;
    return mask.replaceAll("*", () => str[i++] || "");
}

console.log(applyMask("123456789", "(***)-***-***")); // "(123)-456-789"
console.log(applyMask("123456", "***-** *")); // "123-45 6"
```

For support in old browsers you would use a regular expression in order to get the replace-all effect:

```js
function applyMask(str, mask) {
    var i = 0;
    return mask.replace(/\*/g, function () { 
        return str[i++] || ""
    });
}

console.log(applyMask("123456789", "(***)-***-***")); // "(123)-456-789"
console.log(applyMask("123456", "***-** *")); // "123-45 6"
```

Comment: thanks! but this doesnt work for partial match and also not supported in explorer...

Comment: You mean Internet Explorer? The thing from the past? What do you mean with a partial match. Can you update your question to indicate you need compatibility with IE and give an example of what must happen with a partial match?

Comment: Good solution! He will also have to replace "undefined" values if str length is less then mask length. Simply adding .replaceAll("undefined", "") will do the job, or is there another possibility to catch this?

Comment: @ent3, can be done with `str[i++] || "*"`, which will leave the asterisk untouched. (Updated).

Comment: @trincot - great idea - changed to str[i++] || "", in order to leave the original string as is

Comment: The original string will anyhow be left as is, since strings are immutable.

Comment: yep right, I meant to return same string only with formatting -  without adding the asterisks.

Comment: Alright, I aligned my answer with that.